# Are "Among …, include(s) ….” constructs illogical?

Tags: grammar

[This website](https://quizlet.com/9195418/gmat-verbal-flash-cards/) implies that "Among …, include(s) ….” constructs are untenable. It says that the sentence:

> “Among the skills tested on the standardized tests given to military pilots includes orthographic imagination”

is illogical, because it uses both "Among" and "includes" when only one of these may be used at a time. The website also says it is acceptable to say “Among the skills is X,” or to say “The skills include X,” but not “Among the skills include X. ”

I don’t understand this, because in other websites I could see “Among ….. , include(s)  …." For example, from [here](http://www.bestcollegereviews.org/top/online-masters-in-higher-education-administration-degree-programs/):

> The University of Louisville’s online program consists of 36 credit hours, with 6 credits transferrable. **Among** the core courses **include** Philosophy of Higher Education, The American College and University, and Educational Resource Management in Postsecondary Education.

Incidentally, if "Among …, include(s) ….” constructs are acceptable, what is the subject of the verb *include*?

Comment: Hi @User152425MH. Welcome to ELU! I've formatted your question to make it a bit easier to read, and have added links as we prefer sources to be quoted.

Comment: Logic has very little to do with linguistic realities.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that these sentences are ungrammatical is not that use of *include* and *among* is redundant; they are ungrammatical because each casts an *among* phrase as its subject.

> *Among X include(s) Y.

Here are unimpeachably grammatical revisions of your examples:

> The standardized tests given to military pilots include orthographic imagination among the skills tested.
>
> Philosophy of Higher Education, The American College and University, and Educational Resource Management in Postsecondary Education are included among the core courses.

It's quite true that both of these could be more gracefully expressed; but that is a matter of style, not grammaticality.

I think what you're seeing in both of these examples is "composition error": the authors start out writing one thing, then decide on an alternative  construction, and never get around to tidying up the mess.

Comment: Is `Among X include(s) Y` correct or not? I find it very familiar in writing.

Comment: @zyxue It is not correct, unless bare *include* is employed in the imperative.

Comment: What do you mean by "bare include is employed in the imperative", please

Comment: @zyxue Uninflected *include* as a command: "Among your questions, include details!"

Comment: @StoneyB, I recently came to get confused about this again. So `Among X include Y.` is wrong, but `Among X, include Y.` is correct? Is that right, just a coma is the difference?

Comment: @zyxue Not really. I inserted the comma only to make it a little clearer that *include* is an imperative; the comma is not strictly necessary. What **is** necessary is that you avoid a construction in which the preposition phrase *among X* acts (or appears to act) as the subject of the verb *include*.